# Is Vulkan's VkMemoryHeapFlagBits missing values?

Tags: memory, enumeration, vulkan

At Vulkan specs 1.0.9 (pg. 180), we have the following:

```
typedef struct VkMemoryHeap {
  VkDeviceSize size;
  VkMemoryHeapFlags flags;
} VkMemoryHeap;
```

and this description:

> • size is the total memory size in bytes in the heap.
>
> • flags is a bitmask of attribute flags for the heap. The bits specified in flags are:

```
typedef enum VkMemoryHeapFlagBits {
VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT = 0x00000001,
} VkMemoryHeapFlagBits;
```

But when I query `VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties`  I've got flags with zero values. My code matches the output from Vulkan SDK vkjson_info.exe tool, which output a JSON file with properties from my GPU.

Is something missing here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. It is perfectly valid for `VkMemoryHeap::flags` to be 0. A particular flag is either present or absent; it's not an enumeration where the value can attain one of a small number of different possibilities. Usually, flags are independent of one another.

That's how bitflags work; they represent boolean conditions. A particular flag is either present or absent. If a flag is present, then the object attains the meaning that the flag defines. If it is absent, then the object *doesn't* have that meaning.

A heap with `VK_MEMORY_HEAP_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT` means exactly what the specification says it means: "the heap corresponds to device local memory". A heap without that flag set means that heap *does not* "correspond to device local memory".

The specification requires that *at least* one heap have this flag set. But that's all.