# Vulkan memoryHeaps and their memoryTypes

Tags: linux, heap-memory, vulkan

[image]

Above is a picture summarizing my understanding on memoryHeap and their memoryTypes generated by Vulkan for a given system setup. Thanks to the answers on this topics shared by @NicolBolas [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44370072/5722359), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36750650/5722359), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36437023/5722359) and an answer by @krOoze [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48243730/5722359).

Still, I have a few **outstanding questions** that **I like help on** and I have indicated them **in red** and elaborated below per comment of @NicolBolas.

**Questions**

1. Why are there 9 memoryType in sysRam when there are only 4x RAMs?
   What is the physical meaning of each memoryType? How to use each of
   these memoryType?
2. Why are there 2 memory types for GPU RAM? Does this mean each
       memoryType of the GPU RAM is 6144MB/2 = 3072MB?
3. Is there a size limit to each memoryTypes? If yes, how to discover
       their limits?
4. Why are the free memory reported by Vulkan and cat /proc/meminfo
       different?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please don't put questions in images. If you have a question, make it real text.

Comment: @NicolBolas,  I have made my questions in real text.

Comment: @NicolBolas,  I had earlier put my questions in the picture to relate my question to the matter. Simpler to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance... What does this have to do with programming and development?

Comment: @jww by better understanding what memoryHeaps and memoryTypes are in Vulkan and the meaning of their associated variables `propertyFlags` and `flags`, I will be better understand how to write my Vulkan application. :)

Comment: Q 1. and 2. are exact duplicates of [Why does vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties return multiple identical memory types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242445/why-does-vkgetphysicaldevicememoryproperties-return-multiple-identical-memory-ty#48243730) and 1. specifically answered there. Q nr. 2. will likely work similarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [metaquestion] Why is X in Vulkan?

Because it is allowed by the Vulkan specification. Rest is implementation detail, and only the implementer\vendor knows for sure, and may depend on how well he slept.

> 1. Why are there 9 memoryType in sysRam when there are only 4x RAMs? What is the physical meaning of each memoryType? How to use each of these memoryType?

Answered in [Why does vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties return multiple identical memory types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242445/why-does-vkgetphysicaldevicememoryproperties-return-multiple-identical-memory-ty#48243730). One for `VkBuffer`s, one for `VkImage`s, and one per depth format (i.e. 7). Equals 9; mystery solved.

> 2. Why are there 2 memory types for GPU RAM? Does this mean each memoryType of the GPU RAM is 6144MB/2 = 3072MB?

Likely similar reason as 1. I speculate one for `VkBuffer`s, one for `VkImage`s. Someone with NVIDIA could test with `vkGetXMemoryRequirements`.

It does not neccessarily mean RAM/2. It is not completely out of the question, but then again implementer should instead expose separate Heap if that is so.

> 3. Is there a size limit to each memoryTypes? If yes, how to discover their limits?

Roughly the Heap size. You may get significantly less due to fragmentation. And due to other processes sharing the same. Your impl may also allocate some itself for its internal needs.

You discover the limit when you get `VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY`. (BTW mostly works the same as on CPU side, where you get `bad_alloc`).

There is limit to size of single allocation (not recommended to allocate > 4 GB), and to the count of allocations too (`maxMemoryAllocationCount`).

> 4. Why are the free memory reported by Vulkan and cat /proc/meminfo different?

AFAIK Vulkan does not report free memory. The `VkMemoryHeap` shows **total** memory:

> `size` is the total memory size in bytes in the heap.

Comment: Vulkan reported 25.20GB instead of 32.81GB of total memory? 7.61GB appears to be missing. Do you know why?

Comment: @SunBear Because [metaanswer] above -- it is allowed. It seems to be exactly 75 %. That is a value over which typically it is problematic to allocate anything due to fragmentation (not even considering other processes as well as the driver, an your app also need this memory). Just a speculation. You need to ask NVIDIA.

Comment: For comparison, on AMD I get a bit less than 4 GB on a system with 8 GB RAM.

Comment: I will write to Nvidia to inquire and get back to you.

Comment: PS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/calculating-graphics-memory seems to imply that it will always be half the total RAM on Windows +- other limits imposed by the driver.

Answer (score 3):

> Why are there 9 memoryType in sysRam when there are only 4x RAMs? What is the physical meaning of each memoryType? How to use each of these memoryType?
>
> Why are there 2 memory types for GPU RAM?

I don't know what you mean by "4x RAMs"; I suspect you're talking about how many physical memory sticks are in your machine. Memory types (or heaps for that matter) don't care about such things.

As for the rest, it is always important to remember how memory works in Vulkan. Heaps represent actual physical RAM to one degree or another. Memory types represent ways of allocating that memory. But *uses* of memory have their own memory type restrictions.

For example, if an image has the color attachment usage parameter, the implementation can force you to use a specific memory type for the memory backing that image. And images that don't have color attachment can be restricted to using other memory types, but not *that* one. And so forth.

Apparently, [NVIDIA does this for certain combinations of usage and formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242445/why-does-vkgetphysicaldevicememoryproperties-return-multiple-identical-memory-ty#48243730). Simply querying the available memory types isn't enough to know how to go about allocating memory. You have to figure out what buffers and images (complete with format and usage parameters) you will use. And then you have to query what restrictions the implementation imposes on them.

Your application must adapt to these restrictions.

> Is there a size limit to each memoryTypes?

It wouldn't make sense for there to be such a thing. [Memory types define how memory is *allocated*, not how much storage is available.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36437023/734069) The latter is the job of memory heaps.

> Why are the free memory reported by Vulkan and cat /proc/meminfo different?

Vulkan has no API to report free memory, only *total* memory. Asking for the amount of free memory is folly. Memory (or at least, virtual pages in your application) are shared by all threads in your application. And GPU memory especially is shared among all processes on the machine. By the time you get an answer back, the amount of memory may have changed. So when you go to allocate memory based on what you were told was available, it may not be available anymore.

Better to allocate first and deal with failure to allocate if it happens.

You can ask for the total memory so that you can decide on how you want to allocate chunks of memory. But that's how you determine what is and is not available, not by querying a size.

Comment: Why is the total memory reported by Vulkan significantly less than `/proc/meminfo`? 26.35GB vs 32.81GB? I had thought that Vulkan reported free memory because the value reported by Vulkan was close to `MemFree` in `/proc/meminfo`.

Comment: Pardon my typo. I meant why Vulkan reported 25.20GB instead of 32.81GB for total memory? 7.61GB appears to be missing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't know anything about the memory types in Vulkan until you ask the driver.

I think the biggest misunderstanding you have is that the memory types are physically separate. As shown, you have two memory heaps, assume 0 is CPU memory, 1 is GPU.  Within those heaps, you have different memory types. Each memory type occupies space within its own heap,  and can use all the heap space or share it with other types.  For each type you'll have different internal allocation methods with different alignment requirements and different allowed uses. There are multiple queries related to memory types including vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements, vkGetImageMemoryRequirements, and others. It all depends on what you're using the memory for.

Also, those memory types are driver dependent, and will vary between vendors (that looks like the current nVidia layout).

Comment: Yes, the GPU is NVidia and driver 396.45 is used, while the sys RAM is G.Skill. I did not understand why G.Skill allocated 7 memoryTypes with `propertyFlags=0` and not allocate just 1 such memoryType. Thank you for pointing out that nature of the size of memoryTypes in relation to its memoryHeap.

Comment: I don't know what G.Skill is but it has nothing to do with any of the memory types. Your memory types come from the driver for the selected physical device, i.e. all of them are reported and handled by the NVidia driver.  You have host side/CPU memory for transfers, device memory overflow, and other uses.